# Entangled diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is it true that the diophantine equation
$$a(x_1^2+x_2^2) + b(x_3^2+x_4^2) + c(x_5^2+x_6^2) = abc$$
has a solution for arbitrary positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$? Yes, it is.

I devised this problem while studying hermitian form theory a few years ago. I though it could be solved by another method. So I posted about it on newsgroup sci.math and Donald Coppersmith gave an elegant solution using Hermite constant. http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3761575

My method can be applied to
$$a(x_1^2+kx_2^2) + b(x_3^2+kx_4^2) + c(x_5^2+kx_6^2) = abc$$
when $k=1,2,3$. Does this type of equation has a solution for other $k$?

I verified it for $1 \le abc \le 10^5$ when $k = 4,5,6,7,8,10$ by computer search. It's easy to find counterexamples for $k=9$ and $k \ge 11$. But, I don't know how to solve the problem yet.

Can you solve it?

Comment: The number of solutions in integers of course.  The formula therefore can not write.  It is better to formulate the equation in another way.  Decision to be endlessly and in this case will simply solve the equation.

Comment: Fix $a,b,c$ positive integers, and also $k$. For there to be a *rational* solution to the general equation I should think it suffices to check locally, because of the Hasse-Minkowski theorem. The only place one needs to check is infinity, because the degree is so big, and this is of course fine. So I think there's always a rational solution.

Comment: To find the integral solutions within the rational ones is some sort of class number problem. Isn't there some fancy way to deal with it as an adelic volume? Maybe there is some mass formula. I wish I understood better how to deal with this question -- there will clearly be a general theory.

Comment: @znt If we would check the solvability of $q(x_1,\dots,x_6) = N$ with a fixes quadratic form $q$, the Hasse-Mikowski theorem could be crucial. But, as to my problem the quadratic form part varies together with a constant part $abc$, so H-M would not be useful much.
For exaple, it is hard to solve even the simplest case $k=1$ by H-M. Clearly, the equation for $k=1$ has a local solution. But the class number varies desultorily according to $a$, $b$, $c$. This is why I call the problem `entangled.'